# Why don't multiple class selectors work with removeClass

Tags: jquery, removeclass

How do I make this work in one statement with multiple classes?

```
<div class="ddd back7">d</div>
<div class="fff back7">f</div>
<div class="ggg back7">g</div>

$('.ddd','.fff','.ggg').removeClass('back7'); //Does not work


$('.ddd').removeClass('back7');//Does
$('.fff').removeClass('back7');//Does
$('.ggg').removeClass('back7');//Does
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qfmgcvkk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the commas in the quotes:

```
$('.ddd, .fff, .ggg').removeClass('back7');
```